# Gulp doesn't work after reinstalling Windows

Tags: npm, gulp

Upon reinstalling `Windows 10` (and `Node.js`), the `gulp` command isn't found. I ran it from my root folder containing `package.json` and the `node_modules` folder. I tried `npm install gulp`, and also `npm install`: `gulp` command still not found. I'm a bit puzzled.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you re install node and npm again? when you re install node try with **npm install -g gulp**

Answer (score 1):

`npm install -g gulp` will install gulp globally, so that you can use it as a command.

A better way to do it, is to use `npm install gulp` (without the -g) to install it into each local project, and fire it off using `npm start` scripts in each project's package.json.

Comment: About "A better way to do it, is to use npm install gulp (without the -g)" : that's exactly what I did as I mention in the question. Didn't work.

Comment: Try `npm install -g gulp` to begin with.  After that is working, you can try other ways of installing it.

Comment: Also, check that C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm is in your system environment variables.

Comment: Worked, thanks! Sorry I had to accept @hackemateninja's answer though as it was posted a few minutes before yours...